# How to set the fixed icon rather than display it on hover in VSCode treeview?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am develop an vscode extension, i have a requirement,
how to set the fixed icon rather than display it on hover?

this is my configuration of
package.json:

```
        "commands": [
            {
                "command": "fileExplorer.refreshFile",
                "title": "Refresh",
                "icon": {
                    "light": "resources/refresh-flat.png",
                    "dark": "resources/refresh-flat.png"
                }
            },
            {
                "command": "fileExplorer.refreshRoot",
                "title": "Refresh",
                "icon": {
                    "light": "resources/refresh-flat.png",
                    "dark": "resources/refresh-flat.png"
                }
            },
            {
                "command": "fileExplorer.openFolder",
                "title": "View in Explorer",
                "icon": {
                    "light": "resources/folder-open.png",
                    "dark": "resources/folder-open.png"
                }
            },
            {
                "command": "fileExplorer.openFile",
                "title": "Open File"
            }
        ],
        "menus": {
            "view/title": [
                {
                    "command": "fileExplorer.refreshRoot",
                    "when": "view == fileExplorer",
                    "group": "navigation"
                }
            ],
            "view/item/context": [
                {
                    "command": "fileExplorer.refreshFile",
                    "when": "view == fileExplorer",
                    "group": "inline"
                },
                {
                    "command": "fileExplorer.openFolder",
                    "when": "view == fileExplorer",
                    "group": "inline"
                }
            ]
        }
```

[image]

when hovering the file/directory the icon will be displayed. but how to let it shows unconditionally?

[image]

Comment: they are commands to apply to the item, you can control the icon in front of the item, showing all the command icons for all the items will give a very cluttered UI, only show them for the current/hover item

Answer (score 0):

You can **partially** control that.

Using `"workbench.view.alwaysShowHeaderActions": true` on your Settings, the icons on headers (panel titles) will be *always on*.

But, for the elements on each panel (like the files in Explorer panel), there is no setting available. If you really miss this, I suggest you to open a Feature Request in VS Code repo https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose.

Hope this helps